# didChangeAuthorizationStatus not called after changing status

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have a problem where the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus` is not being called after the user either (1) accepts or (2) declines my request to use location services. By placing out different `NSLog` statements, I have reached the conclusion that the method is called when I request authorization, but not when the user makes a choice. Have anyone had the same issues? If so, how did you solve them?

Here's how I initialize my `location manager`:

```
if (_locationManager == nil) {
  NSLog(@"Creating location manager");
  _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  _locationManager.delegate = self;
  _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
  NSLog(@"Not determined");
  if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"dynamicNotifOn"]) {
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
  } else {
    [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
  }
} else if (...) {...
```

and here's the method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
  NSLog(@"Callback");
  if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
    NSLog(@"Authorized");
    [_mainButton setIsLoading:NO];
    [self startGettingLocation];
  } else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
    NSLog(@"Denied");
    _currentState = CurrentStateError;
    [_mainButton setUpButtonForState:_currentState];
  }
}
```

After I press the button that initializes the location manager (the top code-block), this is what the console prints out:

```
Creating location manager
Not determined
Callback
```

And then I make a choice in the AlertView that pops up:

```
*nothing*
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case the problem was in non-main thread.
Just make sure you creating location manager on the main thread.

Comment: This really did the trick! I just attempted to request the permissions on the main thread, but _creating_ the CLLocationManager is at least as crucial!

Answer (score 2):

There few strange thing in the example above:

1. The delegate call back locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus: is called with NotDetermined status?!? In the documentation is clearly written that delegate callback method will be called ONLY when there is change in the authorization status, but in the above example there is not.May be a bug.
2. In Paulw11 answer is stated that we have to always request permission even if the user is already authorized the application?!? By my opinion the application first have to call CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus and request authorization only if the authorization is NotDetermined (i.e. user is still doesn't authorized our app) - that is also stated in the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check for `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` - simply request authorisation every time -

```
if (self.locationManager == nil) {
  NSLog(@"Creating location manager");
  self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  self.locationManager.delegate = self;
  self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

  if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"dynamicNotifOn"]) {
     [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
  } else {
     [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
  }
}
```

When I use your delegate method I get the following output -

```
2015-01-15 12:07:43.357 LocationAuthDemo[9942:500036] Callback
2015-01-15 12:07:51.389 LocationAuthDemo[9942:500036] Callback
2015-01-15 12:07:51.389 LocationAuthDemo[9942:500036] Authorized
```

Do any of the methods you call from the delegate method update UI elements?  If so you should dispatch them on the main queue.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply. 

I have now made that change, but I'm still struggling with the same problem. After the user accepts or declines my request, the method is not called.

Comment: And no, they don't update any UI elements - it simply starts a timer and the location updates. My print statement is not called either. I'll try to dispatch it to the main queue though to see if that works.

Comment: How do you declare the `locationManager` property? Any chance that it has been released?

Comment: Here is the sample code I used to test - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/84b18044942e2ceea52a

Comment: I declare it in the `@interface` section of the `implementation (.m)` file. I doubt it has been released, I used `strong and nonatomic`. 

Yes, I have done the exact same thing as you - yet my `NSLog`-statement, and other methods are not called in the method. This is to me a complete mystery

Comment: Is this class a view controller?

Comment: Yes this class is a `ViewController` - with further testing I can confirm that the `locationManager` object is not released - when I press the button again (the same one that checks if it's `nil` and then creates it), the object is not recreated - hence it was never released (I believe)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68847/discussion-between-paulw11-and-alekplay).

Comment: Was there any resolution, I have the same/similar problem on the first start. On any subsequent start the delegate is called correctly.

Comment: They were setting location manager to nil somewhere else in their code.

Comment: Asking for permissions without user notification and ignoring of current status can lead to bad UX and crashes in the future.

Comment: Asking for permission provides the user notification if required. You may choose to provide an initial notification as to why you are about to ask for a permission but really your use of a permission should be reasonably obvious and the permission request should be linked to an action; e.g. If I click an "add photo" button then I can reasonably expect to be prompted to grant access to the photo library.